# How can you make new form as a copy (in runtime) of an already shown form?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, vb.net-2010

I am trying to make a form that functions as "READ/OPEN MAIL".. so what I want is to have multiple forms (which is a copy, with both the designer and form functions e.g. buttons and codes) when I open multiple mails.

I know how to create a new window but I do not know how to copy the designer codes and functions from anoher form and apply it to the newly created form.  I have searched google but it only directs me to different questions.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is create a variable of the type of your class, then show it using the Show method.

i.e.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myform As Form1 = New Form1
    myform.Show()
End Sub
```